# Get POST request when using Router middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I'm using Passport to authenticate my users on NodeJS. Currently I'm using ExpressJS and I'm trying to route my traffic. I currently use the following code:

**website.js (main file)**

```
require("./routes.js")(app);
```

**routes.js**

```
var pages = {
    home: require("./pages/home"),
    about: require("./pages/about"),
    register: require("./pages/register"),
    login: require("./pages/login"),
    api: require("./api/index")
};

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use("/", pages['home']);
    for (page in pages) {
        app.use("/" + page, pages[page]);
    }

    app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        req.redirect("/");
    });
}
```

**register.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("register", { page: "Register", message: req.flash("registerMessage") });
});

app.post("/", passport.authenticate("register", {
    successRedirect: "/about/",
    failureRedirect: "/register/",
    failureFlash: true,
    successFlash: "Logged in!"
}));

module.exports = router;
```

The problem I am facing is that POST requests to this will result in a 404. The page is not found. The GET request (so /register) properly shows the registration form, but upon submitting I get a 404. If I change `router.get("/", function(req,res){})` to `router.use("/", function(req, res, next) {})`, I will get HTTP 500 errors when I call "Next()" (Can't set headers after they are sent.), and POST still doesn't work.

Could anyone tell me how to correctly catch POST requests behind router middleware?

Comment: Could you post the 500 error you are getting when using router.use?

Comment: The headers error is because you are moving passport.authenticate inside the function, and calling it yourself. This no longer makes it middleware specifically, and it tries to change the headers already provided by Express. Unsure about the POST issue, I'll try some sample code.

Comment: @RubenRutten Could you answer your own question? This will close the question and make the solution more apparent to future readers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### I solved my issue

I solved my issue by using the following:

```
router.route("/")
    .get(function(req, res, next) {
        res.render("register", { page: "Register", message: req.flash("registerMessage") });
    })
    .post(passport.authenticate("register", {
        successRedirect: "/about/",
        failureRedirect: "/register/",
        failureFlash: true,
        successFlash: "Logged in!"
    }));
```